# Renormalization Point for Coulomb Potential?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

In [Introduction to Quantum Field Theory](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic521209.files/QFT-Schwartz.pdf) by Matthew Schwartz at page 177 he explains that we use the renormalization point $p_0=0$ in order to derive Eq. 17.54:

\begin{equation}
    \tilde{V}(p)= \frac{e_R^2}{p^2} \left( 1 + \frac{e_R^2}{2 \pi^2} \int_0^1 dx \, x (1-x)\ln \left[ 1- \frac{p^2}{m^2} x(1-x) \right] + \mathcal{O}(e_R^4) \right) \, .
\end{equation}

Two pages later, i.e. at page 179, below Eq. 17.69 he writes rather cryptically

> "Note that we moved the reference value of the charge from $p= 0$ to $p=m_e$. This is natural, because the simple log dependence in this formula comes from the limit $p≫m_e$, so near $p=m_e$ we should match on to the exact formula with the $p/m_e$ corrections"

**At which point did this change of reference value happen?** He uses Eq. 17.54 directly, which holds for $p_0=0$ to derive Eq. 17.62. and Eq. 17.64 and these are the direct motivation for Eq. 17.69, which apparently holds for $p_0= m_e$ instead.

In his book *Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model*, which is almost equal to the script linked at the beginning of the question, Eq. 16.65 is Eq. 17.64 in the script and there he writes

> In this case, for simplicity, we have defined the renormalized charge, $e_R≡e_{eff}(m)$, at $Q=m$ rather than at $Q=0$. (One could also define $e_R$ at $Q=0$, as with the Uehling potential; however, then one would need to include the full $m$ dependence to regulate the $m=0$ singularity.)

This is equally mysterious to me, because in the book Eq. 16.56 that holds for $p_0=0$ (the equation above), is used directly to derive Eq. 16.65:

\begin{equation}
e_{\text{eff}}^2(p) :=  1 + \frac{e_R^2}{12 \pi^2}  \ln\left( \frac{-p^2}{m^2}\right)   \, .
\end{equation}

Nevertheless, he claims that this somehow holds for $p_0=m$ although the equation we started with holds for $p_0=0$.